# Maria DB/MySQL difference on comparing TimeStamp

Tags: mysql, date

I have two different development environment which is MySQL 5.6 & Maria DB 10.0

I use WHERE query like `time>="userInputBeginTime"` to limit the minimum date of data.

Unfortunately, the front-side provide wrong date information(in my case, the expected input is date string formatted like "yyyy-MM-dd", but the real input was "Invalid Date" which due to javascript error)

And then i found a difference between MySQL & Maria DB

In MySQL:

```
SELECT NOW() > "Invalid Date" test;
+-----------+
|      test |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
```

In Maria DB:

```
SELECT NOW() > "Invalid Date" test;
+-----------+
|      test |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
```

This difference leads directly to the different result that MySQL returned nothing and Maria DB returned everything.

I think may be they use different methods to compare

My temporary solution is using SQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE 
  NOT ISNULL(CONVERT("userInputBeginTime",datetime)) 
  AND time >= "userInputBeginTime"
```

to force Maria DB return nothing when invalid input was detected.

I would like to know if there is a better solution?

Best Regards

Comment: `SELECT @@SQL_MODE;` on both servers.  Do the values match?

Comment: Hi, thank you. @Michael-sqlbot

They both return

    +------------+
    | @@sql_mode |
    +------------+
    |            |
    +------------+

Both of them are installed using the default configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `STR_TO_DATE` to parse the string as a date in the format you expect.  This function would return `NULL` if it cannot parse the date in the format specified.  Your bad JavaScript input would fall into this category and should produce `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(userInput, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL AND
      <other conditions here>
```

[STR_TO_DATE in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/str_to_date/)
[STR_TO_DATE in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)